# iOS RestKit POST Response Content type - is not being set properly

Tags: php, ios, restkit

i set

```
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/json"];
```

& in php server script

```
header('content-type:text/json;charset=utf-8');
```

But still getting

```
Error: .... NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/json}
```

Comment: so why aren't you using application/json ?

Comment: here  why 
`[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/json"];` isn't working ?

Comment: in the php script, why are you using `text/json`? you'd need to show more code to understand why your `setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:` isn't used but really the mime type you're using should be improved...

Comment: application/json worked :) 
but i am interested to know about why 'text/json' is not being set in object manager's header.

Comment: Would need to see more code, could be a mix up between object manager instances